# Running Xcodes UITesting on Jenkins never fails a Test

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, junit, xcode-ui-testing

I have built a simple UITesting framework for one of my apps built in Xcode.  2 of the tests pass and one purposefully fails:

```
XCTAssertTrue(false)
```

I am using the Jenkins Xcode plugin and am using the post-built action: Publish JUnit test result report.

Jenkins successfully launches the simulator and runs all 3 tests.  It also successfully picks up the failure in the logs:

```
Failing tests:
-[LightAlarmUITests testFailingTest()]
** TEST FAILED **
```

However, the Test Results Analyzer (plugin installed) shows all 3 tests are passing. When I inspect the test-results/*.xml file I see the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<testsuite failures="1" errors="0" hostname="Charlies-MacBook-Pro.local" name="LightAlarmUITests" tests="3" time="21.0" timestamp="2016-12-20T16:24:33.125Z">
<testcase classname="LightAlarmUITests" name="testFailingTest" time="6.372"/>
<testcase classname="LightAlarmUITests" name="testShowSettingsPage" time="7.167"/>
<testcase classname="LightAlarmUITests" name="testShowSoundAlarmsPage" time="7.594"/>
</testsuite>
```

As you can see in the xml, it is not marking individual test cases as pass or fail, but instead marking a failure against the entire test suite.

Does anyone know how to mark pass/fails against individual test cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a pull request open to fix this issue.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/xcode-plugin/pull/75

Comment: Thanks Skycamefalling. It says I have to wait an hour to give the bounty so I will be back.  I have spent days working on this so really appreciate your help here :)

Comment: No problem! We have been looking at the same issue for a while too.

Comment: I have now stopped using Jenkins with UITesting.  A bug that falsely passes every test is probably one of the worst things that Jenkins could do, IMHO.  Not addressing the pull request for months that fixes that bug is probably the second worst thing.

Comment: This has been merged into master.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is Xcode 8 changed the way of XML of UI test report. JUnit plugin is not able to parse this XML to generate a test report. I have used [XCPretty](https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty) mediator that converts Xcode 8 XML report into JUnit supported XML. You can find more details at https://blog.talentica.com/2017/04/04/use-xcode-8-with-jenkins/